# Crear un contador dentro de una función en Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, bucles

Esta es una duda bastante simple pero no consigo saber porqué no me funciona este script.

Es más grande mi código, pero lo he simplificado para que sea más fácil dar una respuesta.

Mi script es el siguiente:

```
global numero
numero = 0

def contador(num):
    num=num+1
    return num

while True:
    contador(numero)
    print(numero)
    input("Pulsa enter para sumar: ")
```

Quiero que cada vez que se ejecute la función acceda a `numero` y le sume `1`. También agradecería si alguien me pudiese explicar un poco la forma de modificar variables desde dentro de una función (globals, parámetros, returns, etc)

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Porque no creas un objecto con una variable de clase que sea contador=0 y cuando llames al objecto.contador(num) reescriba esa variable

Comment: @FDelgado esa solución también la tengo en cuenta, pero me gustaría hacerla por medio de una función, un saludo.

Comment: Si quieres seguir con esa opción porque no crear la variable en mayusculas de esta forma: `NUMERO = 0`, esto hará que la variable sea global y puedas manejarla en cualquier lugar, incluso importarla.

Comment: No puedes modificar una variable que le pasas como parámetro a una función (es decir, puedes modificar la copia local, pero eso no afectará a la que está fuera). En tu ejemplo, lo mismo da que `numero` sea global que no. Lo que recibe la función es una copia (`num`) y modifcar esa copia no afecta a la variable `numero`.

Comment: F.Delgado la variables en mayúscula no significan nada sintácticamente, son una **convención para indicar que constantes pero el intérprete las trata exactamente igual que cualquier otro identificador**. El problema aquí es que `global` no se usa para declarar una variable como global sino para indicar dentro de la función que se use una variable definida a nivel de módulo en vez de crear una variable local a la función, es decir `global numero` en todo caso va dentro de `contador`.

Comment: Debes decidir si quieres modificar una variable global desde la función, en cuyo caso usa `global` dentro de ella, no retornes nada y no le pases nada como parámetro o si quieres que retorne el resultado de la suma, en cuyo caso en el `while` puedes hacer `contador = contador(numero)` y prescindir de `global`. Las variables globales por múltiples razones deben usarse con cuidado, cuando esté justificado su uso y no existan mejores alternativas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se entiende cuál es el objetivo que persigues, pero la solución que das no parece muy apropiada. Veamos si te va mejor alguna de estas propuestas, según cuál sea tu objetivo:

## Objetivo: Crear un contador

Si lo que quieres es crear una función que cada vez que la llamas te devuelva un nuevo valor que se va incrementando de uno en uno, no hay ninguna necesidad de variables globales. Tienes tres posibles enfoques:

### Solución 1: Usar una clase

Puedes definir una clase que tenga un atributo donde guarda el valor de la cuenta, y un método que lo incremente y te retorne el resultado:

```
class Contador(object):

  def __init__(self, inicial=0):
    self.numero = inicial

  def siguiente(self):
    self.numero += 1
    return self.numero
```

Se usaría así, por ejemplo (no voy a hacer un bucle infinito, sino uno que se repita sólo 5 veces):

```
cuenta = Contador()

for i in range(5):
   print(cuenta.siguiente())
```

### Solución 2: Usar un generador

Un generador es un tipo especial de función python que tiene la instrucción `yield` en algún punto. Al ejecutar esa función, no se ejecuta en realidad, sino que se crea un tipo de objeto sobre el que puedes hacer `next(objeto)`. Cada vez que haces `next()` sobre él, la función se ejecuta, avanza hasta encontrar `yield` y allí se pausa, hasta que vuelvas a hacerle `next()`. A la vz el `yield` retorna cualquier valor que quieras.

Usando esta idea:

```
def contador():
  numero = 0
  while True:
    numero += 1
    yield numero
```

Y para usarlo en un programa:

```
cuenta = contador()
for i in range(5):
   print(next(cuenta))
```

### Solución 3: Usando atributos de función

Vale, este enfoque es muy raro y no lo recomiendo, pero sólo por completar. En python las funciones son objetos, y puedes "engancharles" atributos para guardar en ellos cosas. Podemos usar un atributo para guardar el valor de la cuenta y que así la función pueda "recordarlo" de una llamada a otra.

```
def cuenta():
    cuenta.numero += 1
    return cuenta.numero
cuenta.numero = 0
```

Que usaríamos así:

```
for i in range(5):
  print(cuenta())
```

## Objetivo: Usar una variable global para la cuenta

No veo por qué en este caso necesitas dos (como en tu solución), basta solo una:

```
cuenta = 0
def contador():
  global cuenta
  cuenta+=1

for i in range(5):
  contador()
  print(cuenta)
```

## Objetivo: Hacer una función que pueda cambiar el valor que recibe como parámetro

Aquí no se busca que la función cambie una variable global, sino que de algún modo yo pueda hacer `contador(n)` y se cambie el propio valor de la `n` que le estoy pasando como parámetro.

Este enfoque parece el más cercano a tu pregunta original y como ya te hemos respondido en los comentarios, no puede hacerse porque la función opera sobre una copia del parámetro.

*Sin embargo...* (**DISCLAIMER** código sucio, no lo hagan en sus casas), si lo que le pasas a la función es una lista, aunque no puedes cambiar la lista en sí, lo que sí puedes es cambiar lo que contiene. Esto por tanto sería lo más parecido a lo que preguntabas:

```
def incrementa_elemento(n):
  n[0]+=1

# Programa principal
numero = [0]   # No necesita ser global
for i in range(5):
   incrementa_elemento(numero)
   print(numero[0])
```

## Conclusión

Ni que decir tiene que el último ejemplo es un "hack" que no debería usarse. La solución con variables globales debe evitarse en lo posible. La que usa atributos de una función es muy rara y poco recomendable.

Las soluciones más ortodoxas serían las que usan una clase o un generador. La elección entre uno y otro es ya cuestión de gustos.

Comment: Vaya, te agradezco muchísimo tu respuesta tan elaborada, es genial que haya gente así en la comunidad, respecto a mi duda, me la has solucionado por completo, de nuevo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Al final he optado por hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
numero = 0

def contador():
    global suma_a
    suma_a=numero+1

while True:
    contador()
    numero=suma_a
    print(numero)
    input("suma")
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda, un saludo.