# Python¿Cuántas veces se ejecutó esta función?

Tags: python

```
def contar():
b = 1
```

Como puedo hace que cada vez que se ejecute esta función "b" aumente en uno solo con la misma función? Básicamente quiero que la función pueda contar por si misma cuantas veces es llamada.

Comment: Aqui tienes varias soluciones [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171626/crear-un-contador-dentro-de-una-funci%C3%B3n-en-python-3-6)]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar una variable global que vas incrementando cada vez que se llama la función:

```
contador = 0

def contar():
  global contador
  contador = contador + 1
  print("contar() ha sido llamado " + str(contador) + " veces")  

contar()
contar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es definir un atributo en la función, y que este incremente cada vez que se llama la función.

```
def foo():
    if hasattr(foo,"count"):
        setattr(foo,"count",foo.count + 1) #También sirve foo.count += 1
    else: 
        foo.count = 1 #Solo se ejecuta la primera vez que se llama a la función
```

Se usa

- [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) para verificar si la función ya se ejecutó una vez para solo incrementar el contador actual.
- [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) para que en caso de que la función ya se haya ejecutado al menos una vez se incremente el contador en uno. Esto se puede hacer de la misma manera con el operador `+=`.

Esto va a dejar a al contador descubierto para otras funciones y/o objetos, hasta para usuarios si se trata de una librería. Considera añadir guiones bajos al nombre para que sea *"difícil"* de acceder.

```
foo.__count__
```